# Android Animations Autodesk Maya

Tags: android

I saw this 3D program call Autodesk Maya for 3D animations. Now I had draw my hero in 3D in this program and make him run, just (animation), so here is question: Is possible to put this animations in Android program ? If not, i read you can do animations in openGl, but I only saw  tutorials to draw 3D not doing animations. I my mind I have like 3D pepole who can move and shot... so how can I do this in android ?

Thank you

Comment: If you like Maya, you can also check out 3ds Max.  It's normally $3500, but you can get the student version for free, and I've never noticed a difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout PowerVR and the PVR system.  You can create files from Maya and use PVR Shaman.  It's a complex field but works very well.  It's cross platform too.

http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-faq.asp